# For iOS, which is easier and faster to implement: Urban Airship or Parse for push notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios, urbanairship.com, parse-platform

Looking to know which is easier and faster to implement in order to send out push notifications. This is going from start(account creating) to finish(releasing to app store). 
Anyone had any experience with both or one?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see the FAQ for the types of questions you should ask. This isn't one of them.

Comment: Writing your own should only take a couple of days...

Comment: @tc. If you know how, then yes. If you don't, it is better to use some free solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm Matt from Parse. Push is arguably one of the most complicated features to add to an iOS application and we spend a lot of our time making this process as easy as possible for you. We have a [great tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications) on getting the right certificates setup and an in depth [Push Guide](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/iOS) to help you get started with our API.

Our pricing model is straight forward (you pay for the number of pushes you sent and the first million per month are free) and we have some really cool features. You can use 'channels' to send pushes to predefined segments of your users or make use of our data storage features to push to really targeted and dynamic segments of your users. With the second option you can basically save any data you want (user's location, age, interest, etc) and writes queries to target exactly the segment you are trying to reach.

Combined with our new Push Console, you don't need any technical skills to send these notifications later.

I know I may be biased since I work at Parse, but as an iOS developer myself I think you'll be delighted by our super easy to use API. We've spent countless hours crafting an API that would be easy to use and familiar to iOS developers.

If you have any questions, send us any questions at feedback@parse.com.

Comment: Thank you for your response Matt. Very informative. I am very interested in using parse. I will be sending over another question at the email you provided.

Comment: @MGA: Hello, I have liked the Parse interface very much. However my concern is that they allow 1 million requests per month. And every time data is saved to or read from, it construes a request. So a malicious user can keep spamming the save button and exhaust all the resources. Is there any way to counter that?

Answer (score 0):

Each service has it's pro's and con's.  It would be in your best interest to read the documentation on both and make your own decision.

Comment: I think it's a good question. Reading documentation is not an adequate substitute for experience using it, and if someone has experience with both they can save him hours of work by sharing their experience.